# Print n lines before and m lines after match with pdfgrep

Tags: pdf

How can I print n lines before and m lines after match with pdfgrep.

The `-C` option doesn't seem to go beyond one line. Maybe one can pipe the output of pdfgrep to another program or there is an alternative to pdfgrep that can do this.

Comment: Maybe add your pdfgrep version? According to [this](https://gitlab.com/pdfgrep/pdfgrep/issues/5) it seems that newer versions may have working context options.

Comment: I am using 1.4.1

Answer (score 1):

`-A`, `-B`, `-C` work correctly and like with GNU `grep` with pdfgrep 2.0 for me.

You can always use (assuming GNU `grep`):

```
pdftotext file.pdf - | grep -A/B/C...
```

(which in my case also appears to be a lot quicker even though both use `poppler`).

Or to work with more than one file, do like `zgrep` does:

```
for file in ./*.pdf; do
  pdftotext "$file" - | grep --label="$file" -H ...
done
```

(adding the `-layout` option to `pdftotext` seems to give a result closer to that of `pdfgrep`. You may also want to squeeze sequences of spacing characters into one space to help with searches for multi-word strings by piping the output of `pdftotext` through `tr -s '[[:space:]]' '[ *]'`)